# Migrate SQL Server database to an SQL Compact database

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server database and want to migrate it to a SQL Compact database. How do I do that?

Thnx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Erik EJ's [blog](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html) has useful SQL CE resources, including his Export2SqlCe tool.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend SQL Server's 'Generate Scripts' command (Right click database, Tasks->Generate Scripts). This will build a script of DDL statements for the objects that you choose. Optionally you can include data within those tables to be scripted.

The resulting scripts can be run within Visual Studio against your .sdf.

Be warned though of some datatypes that SQL Compact doesn't support.

Comment: I know how to create the script but how do I then migrate it a SQL Compact database? Where do I do that?